# Ad banner do not show up suddenly(I am using the ad ID provide by AdMob)

Tags: android, admob, adview

I know many people have asked similar question but no one can help me.

I am developing an android app. At the beginning, I have added the adView in my layout using the test ads ID look like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

I have followed the guide provided by AdMob, updated the app ID in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Scoreboard">
    <activity android:name="com.example.scoreboard.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
</application>
```

My MainActivity is also follow the guide:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Everything work find at the beginning, but somehow the ads doesn't show up suddenly and I find out this message:

```
10-26 11:30:09.622 4049-4186/com.example.scoreboard I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v203404000.203404000.0
10-26 11:30:09.622 4049-4186/com.example.scoreboard I/Ads: HTTP timeout: 60000 milliseconds.
10-26 11:30:09.712 4049-4049/com.example.scoreboard E/MainActivity: The error of ads: {
      "Response Info": {
        "Adapter Responses": [],
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Response ID": "null"
      },
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Message": "No fill.",
      "Code": 3,
      "Cause": "null"
    }
```

As I am using the ads ID and app ID provided by AdMob for testing, I don't know why the ad does not show up suddenly. I have try to use my own app ID, but still the same. Anyone know why this is happening?

I discover 2 exceptions of the ads in my logcat lately after asking this question, hope this can help:

```
10-26 12:36:39.227 4769-4769/com.example.scoreboard W/Ads: #007 Could not call remote method. @28
    com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazf: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.DynamiteOmid
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzard.zzn(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:22)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzard.getVersion(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:31)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdds.zzasx(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddv.call(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzq.zzazk(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdyy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazk.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazn.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdxr.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdds.zzasm(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdfl.zzt(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqz.zzakq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqz.zzakr(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzboz.zzaki(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:39)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzboz.zzakj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:59)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxm.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:40)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:120)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:20)
        at com.example.scoreboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.DynamiteOmid
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:260)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazd.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzard.zzn(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:22) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzard.getVersion(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:31) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdds.zzasx(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:10) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddv.call(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzq.zzazk(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:5) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdyy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:8) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:11) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazk.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:4) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazn.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:103) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdxr.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:5) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdds.zzasm(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdfl.zzt(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:7) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqz.zzakq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:13) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqz.zzakr(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:14) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzboz.zzaki(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:39) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzboz.zzakj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:59) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxm.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:40) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:16) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:120) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:15) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:20) 
        at com.example.scoreboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gm
10-26 12:36:39.227 4769-4769/com.example.scoreboard W/Ads: #007 Could not call remote method. @28
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzard.getVersion(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdds.zzasx(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddv.call(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzq.zzazk(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdyy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazk.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazn.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdxr.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdds.zzasm(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdfl.zzt(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqz.zzakq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqz.zzakr(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzboz.zzaki(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:39)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzboz.zzakj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:59)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxm.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:40)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.5.0:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:120)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:20)
        at com.example.scoreboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Following is the build.gradle of my app:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scoreboard"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use your app ID and test ad ID? What happens there?

Comment: Yes, I have try using my app ID with test ad ID. The result is same, still can't fix it.

Comment: What is play services version you are using? Share your build.gradle

Comment: I have edit the question to share my whole build.gradle at the last part. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Error code is 3 stand for the ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

no need to change anything

it will work for you.

Comment: But I am using the test ads ID for testing, not my own ads ID. It that possible the test ads return the error code 3?

Comment: dont think so
maybe because of your payment pending
is there any error or warning on home page of admob ?

Answer (score -1):

I use this to load ads:

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); //I don't see this in your code
    AdRequest ad = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(ad);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have set the ads size and ads ID in the XML layout file. According to the guide of AdMob, the size and ID can either set programmatically or in the XML. However, I have try your method to load the ads  as well as adding the listener and relevant method. And he problem still exist.

Comment: @lamys yeah, if you put it in XML, no need to use it in code;

Comment: I mean I already added the ads ID, but the adView doesn't show up when I open the app.